# Read a string file as ints into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

I need to write a program that takes an input file with the name, age, and score information of a Golfer (practice.txt). The file then should compare the scores with the par scores for the specific age group. For example: Manny is 14, so he follows the par scores for the 12-15 age group. Manny shot a 5 on hole one, so he made par. I'm having trouble understanding how to compare between the file and the array? Any code or ideas to get me on my way would be great.

*Input File practice.txt:*

**Jay 57 4 3 2 3 5 3 2 3 4**

**Gloria 39 4 4 3 4 3 4 3 3 5**

**Manny 14 5 6 4 6 5 6 4 4 6**

**Joe 3 9 8 8 7 6 6 7 5 7**

*Par Scores Chart:*

```
                           HOLES
AGE             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

4 and under     8   8   9   7   5   7   8   5   8
5 – 7           7   7   8   6   5   6   7   5   6
8 – 11          6   5   6   5   4   5   5   4   5
12 – 15         5   4   4   4   3   4   3   3   4
16 and over     4   3   3   3   2   3   2   3   3
```

*What I have:*

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class imTryingHere {
 public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {

     int [][] ageGroups = 
    {
       {4},
       {7},
       {11},
       {15},
       {100},
    };

    int[][] holePars=
    {
      {8,8,9,7,5,7,8,5,8},
      {7,7,8,6,5,6,7,5,6},
      {6,5,6,5,4,5,5,4,5},
      {5,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,4},
      {4,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3},
   };


  }
}
```

Comment: The general strategy would be to read your data into data structures that would help you to accomplish your goal. If you look at the answer by nakano531 you'll see that's what the code is doing for the most part. The "Par Scores Chart" is hardcoded rather than being read from a file, but the values are placed into a `Map` structure so that it's easy to pull out the par scores by age later. Similarly, the data from the practice file is read into a list of player objects so that it's easy to access and use later. Then both structures are accessed in the `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
// Put age and par scores into Map
static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> ageParsList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>() {
    {put(4,  new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(8, 8, 9, 7, 5, 7, 8, 5, 8)));}
    {put(7,  new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(7, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6)));}
    {put(11, new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5)));}
    {put(15, new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4)));}
    {put(-1, new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3)));}
};

public static List<Integer> getParScoresList(int age) {

    int targetAge = -1;
    for (Integer key : ageParsList.keySet()) {
        if (age <= key) {
            targetAge = key;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ageParsList.get(targetAge);      
}

public static class Player {
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Integer> scoreList;

    public Player(String name, int age, List<Integer> scoreList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age  = age;
        this.scoreList = scoreList;
    }
}

private static List<Player> getPlayerScore() {
    Scanner scan = null;
    try{
          File file = new File(_path_to_file_);
          scan = new Scanner(file); 

          List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();

          while (scan.hasNext()) {
              String name = scan.next();
              int age = scan.nextInt();
              List<Integer> scoreList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
              for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                  scoreList.add(scan.nextInt());
              }
              scan.nextLine(); // last line must have newline character.

              Player player = new Player(name, age, scoreList);
              playerList.add(player);
          }           

          return playerList;
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (scan != null) {
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<Player> playerList = getPlayerScore();

    for (Player player : playerList) {
        List<Integer> parScoresList = getParScoresList(player.age);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int score = player.scoreList.get(i);
            int par   = parScores.get(i);

            // Compare player's score and par score here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A good answer, but I don't really like the hardcoded limits on the loops like: `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`. My next point is more a matter of preference but I find `Scanner` to be a little awkward to use and in this particular case less elegant than the NIO file reading logic proposed by Tong Liu.

Answer (score 0):

[NIO's Files.newBufferedReader() is very good](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

So it will probably look something like this:

```
Path practiceFile = Paths.get("/tmp/practice.txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(practiceFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
{
    Pattern scorePattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)([\\d\\s]+)");
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = scorePattern.matcher(line.trim());
        if (m.matches())
        {
          String name = m.group(1);
          String[] scores = m.group(2).trim().split(" ");
          //do more stuff
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```